# Using colors as variable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, colors

I'd like to create a custom colors in my "GlobalColors.vb" module with sample code below;

```
Public Mycolor1 As Object = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(30, 155, 0, 144)
```

I tried to implement this in one of my panel.

```
Me.Panel1.BackColor = Mycolor1
Me.Panel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(54, 47)
Me.Panel1.Name = "Panel1"
Me.Panel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(200, 100)
Me.Panel1.TabIndex = 0
```

But i have an error like below;

> Could not find type 'TestApp.GlobalColors'. Please make sure that the
>   assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part
>   of your development project, make sure that the project has been
>   successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any
>   CPU.

Could anyone know how to define custom colors and use them in background of panels and other WinForm Control elements?

Comment: This has nothing to do with using colours.  The issue is that that code cannot see the type that `Mycolor1` is declared in.  Can we assume that that error message is generated at run-time or is it at compile-time?  Have you absolutely confirmed that your project is being built successfully, as the error message says?  Are the module and the form in the same project?  Are they ion the same namespace?

Comment: I think you need to post more code.  Are all these in the same namespace?  Is GlobalColor a class, sub, function?  Is it public or private?  Etc.  Need more code.

Answer (score 1):

As described, it works fine for me.  You either have a corrupt setup, or you've described it inaccurately:

```
Module GlobalColors

    Public Mycolor1 As Object = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(30, 155, 0, 144)

End Module

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Panel1.BackColor = Mycolor1
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had `Option Strict On` you would find an error here: `Me.Panel1.BackColor = Mycolor1`

Error:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to
>   'Color'.

Change:

```
Public Mycolor1 As Object = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(30, 155, 0, 144)
```

to:

```
Public Mycolor1 As Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(30, 155, 0, 144)
```

Whether that fixes your original problem I'm not sure, but worth a try.